# Is there a way to use a div as a mold and have multiple (variable amount) on page using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a program that requires multiple bar graphs, but this is a variable amount and can change every time the program is run. How can I copy and paste the div of said bar graph?

The program is meant to take total payment to a team, and divide it amongst the members based on how much time is spent on the project.

I am experimenting with `<template>` but I am unsure what to do from here

```html
<head>
        <style>
            .loadbar
            {
                width: 85px;
                height:700px;
                background-color:#ccc;
                border:5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
                position:absolute;
                border-radius: 10px;
                right: 20%; 
                top: 15%;
            }
            .bar
            {
                width:100%;
                display:block;        
                font-family:'VT323';
                font-size:25px; 
                background-color:#bb9319;
                color:#fff;       
                position:absolute;
                bottom:0;
                height:10%;
                transition: transform 10s;
            }
            .loadbar:hover
            {
                transform: scale(1.2);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <template id="mold">
            <div class="loadbar" id="loadbar">
                <div class= "bar" id ="bar"></strong>
            </div>
        </template>
        
        <script>
            var template = document.getElementById("myTemplate").content;
            characterSelect.appendChild(template);
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: [MDN has some example code that you might find useful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots#using_templates_with_web_components).

Comment: What variable determines how many are created?

Comment: @ggorlen I have not gotten to that part yet because I can't do much without envisioning the future structure of my code which will be based on this question. I have found a good website with a possible answer, I am implementing and will click answer my question once I have figured it out.